# Selenium with Python: select (and click) an element from a table

Tags: python, selenium

I can't figure out why this don't work. The ID is obviously "ReservedDateTime_2022-08-29 14:10:00"

your help would be much appreciated

**Index.html**

```
<div data-function="timeTableCell" data-sectionid="40" data-servicetypeid="632" data-fromdatetime="2022-08-29 14:10:00" class="pointer timecell text-center " style="top: 620px; height:20px; background-color: #1862a8;color:#ffffff; position:relative;" aria-label="2022-08-29 14:10:00" role="row">

                            <script type="text/javascript">
                                                            document.writeln('14:10');
                            </script>14:10

                            <noscript>

                                            <label class="radio pointer inline-block" for="ReservedDateTime_2022-08-29 14:10:00">
                                                            <input type="radio" id="ReservedDateTime_2022-08-29 14:10:00" name="ReservedDateTime" value="2022-08-29 14:10:00"  />
                                                            14:10
                                            </label>
                            </noscript>
            </div>
```

**Python**

```
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_id("ReservedDateTime_2022-08-29 14:10:00").click()
>>
NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css     selector","selector":"[id="ReservedDateTime_2022-08-29 14:10:00"]"}
(Session info: chrome=99.0.4844.74)
```

The div is inside an tbody

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This id

```
ReservedDateTime_2022-08-29 14:10:00
```

looks dynamic in nature since it has date and time.

I'd recommend you to use name instead:

```
name="ReservedDateTime"
```

or

**CSS:**

```
input[name='ReservedDateTime']
```

or **XPath:**

```
//input[@name='ReservedDateTime']
```

**PS :** Please check in the `dev tools` (Google chrome) if we have **unique** entry in `HTML DOM` or not.

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `//input[@name='ReservedDateTime']` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.

You can **click** it like below:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='ReservedDateTime']"))).click()
```

**Imports:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Thank you for replying cruisepandey. I did the check and it looked good! What does it mean when the id is dynamic? The table contains a lot of dates and times and I'm only interested in ReservedDateTime_2022-08-29 14:10:00.

Comment: It could mean that for every time you launch a browser the value is different based on time. Glad we could solve it together, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Datetime may be dynamic for each instance, try with `name` instead.

```
driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'ReservedDateTime')
```